# FluentMigrator & Lock request timeout period exceeded

Tags: sql-server, fluent-migrator

I am shifting my development platform to a virtual machine (using VirtualBox), and have installed Win7, VS2010 and SQL Server Express 2008 R2.  I have a project that uses FluentMigrator to look after the database.

When I (try to) run the initial migration, all console messages come back from FluentMigrator reporting success, but when I look at the database, no changes have been made.  Also, if I try to refresh the schema in SQL Server Management Studio Express within a couple minutes of running the migration, I get a "Lock request timeout period exceeded" message.

Unfortunately SQL Server Express does not come with SQL Profiler.  Is there a way I can look at the queries hitting the database without this?

Any other ideas on why FluentMigrator would be reporting success when there is no success to be found?

Comment: UPDATE: Using the free SQL Profiler http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/, I can see that the queries are hitting the server.  I'm still not sure why the changes aren't being written to the database, though.

Comment: In case it's the same issue I bumped in to, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196463/fluentmigrator-migration-succeeds-but-no-changes-to-db